# Server error 500 when deploy django to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I got following server error 500 when deploying django app to heroku.
I have worked on this problem for 2 days to fix, but have no idea to solve the problems.
I assume djangorestframework cause this problems because it has favicon.ico which leads "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 77" but no idea.

Does anyone detect issues?
Thank you for your support in advance!!

```
2019-07-23T12:03:44.622777+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user atnihs-do-21@hotmail.co.jp
2019-07-23T12:03:51.865737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn alumate.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-07-23T12:03:55.314454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-07-23T12:03:55.130912+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-23 12:03:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-23T12:03:55.132168+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-23 12:03:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:20191 (4)
2019-07-23T12:03:55.132311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-23 12:03:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-23T12:03:55.138103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-23 12:03:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-23T12:03:55.150027+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-23 12:03:55 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-07-23T12:03:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-23T12:04:30.649490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=alumate.herokuapp.com request_id=0f1e339a-08fc-4b93-9c1b-1db28b675f76 fwd="210.150.77.215" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=835ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
2019-07-23T12:04:30.649933+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.197.226 - - [23/Jul/2019:12:04:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"
2019-07-23T12:04:31.116073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alumate.herokuapp.com request_id=381749d5-0137-4017-bd1b-8bb8cb6feef1 fwd="210.150.77.215" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=186ms status=404 bytes=258 protocol=https
2019-07-23T12:04:31.116099+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.197.226 - - [23/Jul/2019:12:04:31 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "https://alumate.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"
```

Settings.py is here

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'rest_framework',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'boards',
    'accounts',
    'auths',
    'my_universities',
    'my_profiles',
    'universities',
    'charts',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'alumate.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'alumate.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                             
STATICFILES_DIRS = [                                                
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' 


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'                                                
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')   


DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

    if not DEBUG:
        import django_heroku
        django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I deleted image files in static folder and ran `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: A `404` is not a `500`. `500` is when your code breaks somewhere. Please post the traceback of the error.

Comment: the 404 for /favicon.ico has nothing to do with it. We cannot help if you're not showing us your logs. You need to create logs (`LOGGING` setting in settings.py) to disk so you can analyse issues in your production instances.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about Logging setting in settings.py.!!!

Comment: I solved the  issue by analyzing the error in the log. The problems was some missing link and files which are comment out in the template. I deleted all and problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1):

For the reference to other people who have similar issues, paste the [code](https://chrxr.com/django-error-logging-configuration-heroku/) below to the bottom of settings.py and run `heroku logs --tail --all [your app name]` after the deployment.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: --app not --all   
And thanks, finally getting somewhere with more visibility!  The problem with turning DEBUG=True as many suggest is that often changes the database you are using, from Postgres to SQLite, which could be the very issue causing the problem.  This allows me to see logs with DEBUG=False